# Function to sort items with an array of keys

Tags: javascript, recursion, sorting

I'm working on a function to sort two elements using several properties. I want to know if the function is well structured.

```
function comparePropsOfAWithB(a, b, props) {
    var prop  = props[0];
    var propA = a[prop];
    var propB = b[prop];

    if (propA === propB) {
        var array = props;
        array.shift();
        return props.length ? comparePropsOfAWithB(a, b, props) : false
    } else if (propA < propB ) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This function is meant to be used alongside the sort method like this:

```
array.sort(function(a,b) { return comparePropsOfAWithB(a,b,["a","b","c"]) })
```

The intent of the function is to compare two objects using several values to determine if they are different. In the example, the key "`a`" will be tested, and if it fails, "`b`" will be tested until the last element of the array is reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how the comparison function for [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works at all: it should return negative, zero, or positive.

Eating up all or part of the `props` argument (due to your `array.shift()` call) is bad practice.

The usage is cumbersome:

> ```
> array.sort(function(a,b) { return comparePropsOfAWithB(a,b,["a","b","c"]) })
> ```

Wouldn't it be nicer to write a `propertyComparator(…)` function that returns a function?

```
array.sort(propertyComparator('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Something like this:

```
function propertyComparator() {
    var props = arguments;
    return function(a, b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            var aProp = a[props[i]];
            var bProp = b[props[i]];
            if (aProp < bProp) return -1;
            if (aProp > bProp) return +1;  
        }
        return 0;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks i only added one line to compare if the properties are equal, i need to be exhaustive if two props are equal i need to check equality in the other props before exiting the function. this is more elegant and really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This `if` construct

> ```
> if (propA === propB) {
>     var array = props;
>     array.shift();
>     return props.length ? comparePropsOfAWithB(a, b, props) : false
> } else if (propA < propB ) {
>     return true
> } else {
>     return false
> }
> ```

can be written in pseudocode like this

```
if (condition) {
    return boolean;
} else if (otherCondition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

if the first condition is true, the `else if` won't be reached so we can rewrite it like

```
if (condition) {
    return boolean;
} 

if (otherCondition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

now the last `if...else if` boils down to if `otherCondition` is true return `true` otherwise return `false`. As the `otherCondition` evaluates to a `boolean` we can simply return this condition like so

```
if (condition) {
    return boolean;
} 

return otherCondition;
```

which leads for your code to

```
function comparePropsOfAWithB(a, b, props) {
    var prop  = props[0];
    var propA = a[prop];
    var propB = b[prop];

    if (propA === propB) {
        var array = props;
        array.shift();
        return props.length ? comparePropsOfAWithB(a, b, props) : false
    }

    return propA < propB;
}
```

which is much simpler and easier to read, **but taking into account the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/96448/29371) of [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success)  this won't help you, because your assumptions regarding the returnvalue of a compare function is wrong.**

---

You should use descreptive meaningful names for naming variables, methods and classes. You shouldn't use abbreviations for naming because this reduces the readability of your code.

So instead of `propA` and `propB` something like `firstItem`and `secondItem` or `firstProperty` and `secondProperty` would be better.